# eth_call for nameExpires(uint256 id)

Tags: python, ens, eth-call

Can someone please explain how I can build the eth_call data param for Registrar nameExpires(uint256 id)

the signature is this: 0xd6e4fa86

The function takes id of label, the namehash. BUT i dont understand how to go from bytes32 to uint256 on the namehash.

```
The registrar works exclusively with label hashes - the keccak256 of the first component of the label (eg, keccak256('ens') for ens.eth). For compatibility with ERC721, these are expressed as uint256 values rather than bytes32, but can be cast backwards and forwards transparently.
```

how do I cast bytes32 to uint256?

after that i need to "hash" the data and pad it?

Please help?

Comment: how do you cast? `bytes32(id)` , it is used all over the contract `BaseRegistrarImplementation.sol`, didn't you check the sources?

Comment: @Nulik I have read the sources of the Solidity files. I was having issues with casting in python.